# Stable isomorphisms of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stably isomorphic groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33589/stably-isomorphic-groups)

If $G$ and $H$ are two groups (finitely presented, if you wish) with the property that $G\times\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $H\times\mathbb{Z}$, does that imply that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: This question gets asked *so* often!


Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Stably isomorphic groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33589/stably-isomorphic-groups) (Hirshon's example is finitely presented).